# Zorin OS 16 - CMake missing the_FoundationConfig.cmake

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm new to Linux and upon reviewing many youtube videos, I settled for Zorin OS 16. I've tried to download Doomsday_Engine and it requires some steps to be ready. One step is this:

```
    cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../doomsday
```

However, I got the following error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
-- Configuring doomsday...
-- Configuring libs...
-- Configuring core...
CMake Error at libs/core/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):

  By not providing "Findthe_Foundation.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "the_Foundation", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "the_Foundation"
  with any of the following names:

    the_FoundationConfig.cmake
    the_foundation-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "the_Foundation" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "the_Foundation_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "the_Foundation" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Have you run `build_deps.py` script, as noted in their [README](https://github.com/skyjake/Doomsday-Engine#the_foundation)? Among other things this script should install `the_Foundation` library.

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. Thought I'd do something new and exciting by learning Linux, guess it's not my cup of tea. Please let me know how to accept your answer as the solution. Cheers mate.